# What common/simple problem would work well as a web app?

Tags: python, beginner, jupyter

**Context**

I'm currently writing a simple tutorial to demonstrate a tool to data scientists and analysts that turns Jupyter Notebooks into web apps. Basically, it discusses setting up the web app as a front end, running some code in the notebook and then returning data to the web app.

**Question**

My question is, what is a small interesting problem in data science that I could solve in the notebook?

I'm looking for something more interesting than doubling an input but smaller/simpler than building a computer vision model.

**Additional information**

As you can probably tell, I am new to data science. Apologies if this is the wrong forum for this type of question.

[Here is the version with a non-interesting problem being solved in the notebook, it may provide more context if needed.](https://anvil.works/learn/tutorials/google-colab-to-web-app)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try solving easy classification problems like with [Iris Dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html) or [Titanic Dataset](https://github.com/minsuk-heo/kaggle-titanic/tree/master/input). You'll find many tutorials dealing with those subjects, and they are basic and famous exercices for someone starting in Data Science.

Comment: That's really useful, thank you.